# If there exists of tournament of 10 vertices how many vertices could have at least 7 wins.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have worked this problem out with brute force and think the answer is 5, but I'm not sure how to show this using a graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a transitive one, where every player beats the people below and loses to the people above, you have one with each score.  You have to take two wins away from the $9$, one from the $8$, add one to the $6$, and add two to the $5$, so reverse $9-5,8-5,9-6$ and you are there.